# app crashing in ipa file only,not crashed when installed with xcode to device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash, xcode8

I am stuck in a very weird situation.When i create an IPA and install it in to any device, its crashing at one fixed point.But when i install directly from xcode to device, it works perfectly fine and no crashes.Tried almost every possible solution available, deleting the build folder, cleaning, removing files and adding them again etc..
Below is the crash log for refernce. Any help would be appreciated THanks

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information: abort() called

Filtered syslog: None found

Last Exception Backtrace: 
0   CoreFoundation          0x185e681c0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib         0x1848a055c objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation          0x185e68108 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
3   Foundation              0x1868565ac -[NSString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:] + 352
4   Foundation              0x186949f5c -[NSString containsString:] + 68
5   TM iSwift               0x100157528 -[KossexViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:] (KossexViewController.m:1373)
6   UIKit                   0x18bd90b20 -[UITableView _delegateWantsHeaderForSection:] + 528
7   UIKit                   0x18bd8f7b0 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 208
8   UIKit                   0x18c180b7c -[UITableViewRowData _ensureSectionOffsetIsValidForSection:] + 348
9   UIKit                   0x18bd8f61c -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 576
10  UIKit                   0x18bd8f380 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 60
11  UIKit                   0x18bd8f1b4 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 220
12  UIKit                   0x18bfed6f0 -[UITableView _rebuildGeometry] + 44
13  UIKit                   0x18bd94b64 -[UITableView didMoveToWindow] + 140
14  UIKit                   0x18bcadc1c -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1544
15  UIKit                   0x18bcd1714 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 92
16  UIKit                   0x18bcacd90 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 156
17  UIKit                   0x18bcacbe8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 792
18  UIKit                   0x18bcb8ad0 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1788
19  UIKit                   0x18bcb83bc -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 828
20  TM iSwift               0x100152428 __34-[KossexViewController createBody]_block_invoke (KossexViewController.m:397)
21  libdispatch.dylib       0x184cf1200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
22  libdispatch.dylib       0x184cf11c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
23  libdispatch.dylib       0x184cf5d6c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
24  CoreFoundation          0x185e15f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
25  CoreFoundation          0x185e13b18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
26  CoreFoundation          0x185d42048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
27  GraphicsServices        0x1877c5198 GSEventRunModal + 180
28  UIKit                   0x18bd1c628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
29  UIKit                   0x18bd17360 UIApplicationMain + 208
30  TM iSwift               0x1001384c0 main (main.m:18)
31  libdyld.dylib           0x184d245b8 start + 4

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed: 
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib  0x0000000184e36014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000184efd460 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib       0x0000000184daa3f4 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib         0x00000001848752d4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib         0x0000000184892cc0 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib         0x00000001848a0844 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib         0x000000018488f66c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib         0x000000018488ef84 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib         0x00000001848a0690 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 0
9   CoreFoundation          0x0000000185e68108 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
10  Foundation              0x00000001868565ac -[NSString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:] + 352
11  Foundation              0x0000000186949f5c -[NSString containsString:] + 68
12  TM iSwift               0x0000000100157528 -[KossexViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:] (KossexViewController.m:1373)
13  UIKit                   0x000000018bd90b20 -[UITableView _delegateWantsHeaderForSection:] + 528
14  UIKit                   0x000000018bd8f7b0 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 208
15  UIKit                   0x000000018c180b7c -[UITableViewRowData _ensureSectionOffsetIsValidForSection:] + 348
16  UIKit                   0x000000018bd8f61c -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 576
17  UIKit                   0x000000018bd8f380 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 60
18  UIKit                   0x000000018bd8f1b4 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 220
19  UIKit                   0x000000018bfed6f0 -[UITableView _rebuildGeometry] + 44
20  UIKit                   0x000000018bd94b64 -[UITableView didMoveToWindow] + 140
21  UIKit                   0x000000018bcadc1c -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1544
22  UIKit                   0x000000018bcd1714 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 92
23  UIKit                   0x000000018bcacd90 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 156
24  UIKit                   0x000000018bcacbe8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 792
25  UIKit                   0x000000018bcb8ad0 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1788
26  UIKit                   0x000000018bcb83bc -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 828
27  TM iSwift               0x0000000100152428 __34-[KossexViewController createBody]_block_invoke (KossexViewController.m:397)
28  libdispatch.dylib       0x0000000184cf1200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
29  libdispatch.dylib       0x0000000184cf11c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
30  libdispatch.dylib       0x0000000184cf5d6c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
31  CoreFoundation          0x0000000185e15f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
32  CoreFoundation          0x0000000185e13b18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
33  CoreFoundation          0x0000000185d42048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
34  GraphicsServices        0x00000001877c5198 GSEventRunModal + 180
35  UIKit                   0x000000018bd1c628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
36  UIKit                   0x000000018bd17360 UIApplicationMain + 208
37  TM iSwift               0x00000001001384c0 main (main.m:18)
38  libdyld.dylib           0x0000000184d245b8 start + 4
```

Comment: What do you do at line 1373 in `KossexViewController.m` ?  Please show your code.

Comment: Looks like it's crashing at some sort of string comparison in `[KossexViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]`. Can't say any more without seeing the code.

Comment: but y its working fine in debug mode then if something is wrong with code @AllanPoole

Comment: It's odd, I'll give you that. But without more context, you're making it very difficult to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see on these lines
(i) `[KossexViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:] (KossexViewController.m:1373`

(ii) `[KossexViewController createBody]_block_invoke (KossexViewController.m:397`

if everythink is perfect then edit your scheme from debug to release mode.